# Inequality for Distribution of points in space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^2.$ We are given $n$ mutually different points $x_1,..,x_n \in \mathbb R^2.$

We can then introduce expressions

$$f_i(x_1,...,x_n) =  n^2 \vert x_i \vert^2 + \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{1}{\vert x_j-x_i \vert^2 }.$$

I would like to know if there exists an explicit constant $c>0$, independent of the points, (as large as possible) such that 
$$ n^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_1,...,x_n) \ge c n^3.$$

*I will do two cases by hand to give you a feeling:*

**$n=1$:** This case is clear, as

$$1+ f_1(x_1) \ge 1 =c1^3$$ with $c=1.$

**$n=2$:** This case is already more tricky, however

$$4 + f_1(x_1,x_2) + f_2(x_1,x_2) =4+ 4(\vert x_1 \vert^2+\vert x_2 \vert^2) + \frac{2}{\vert x_1-x_2 \vert^2}$$
and thus using the parallelogram identity we find 
$$ 4 + f_1(x_1,x_2) + f_2(x_1,x_2)=4+ 2 (\vert x_1-x_2 \vert^2 + 1/\vert x_1-x_2 \vert^2) + 2 \vert x_1+x_2 \vert^2.$$

Now, we may use that $t+1/t  \ge 2$ for $t > 0$ to infer that

$$ 4 + f_1(x_1,x_2) + f_2(x_1,x_2)\ge 4+ 4 = 2^3.$$

So somehow one could conjecture that $c=1$ is possible, but I don't know whether this is true in general.

Comment: just curious; where did this question come from? maybe context could help lead to a solution

Comment: For clarification, in your definition of $f$... let's take the example $n=3$. Would you include for $f_1$ both $j=2, k=3$ and $j=3, k=2$ in the sum? If so, I do believe that all of the terms where $j \neq k$ cancel out by conjugate symmetry of the interior product.

Comment: @LuuBluum good point, I adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think if such $c$ exists, it is less than $1$. For $n = 3$ take equilateral triangle around origin whose vertices are on $x$ distance from origin. Then, vertices are $x \sqrt{3}$ apart from each other, and minimising for $x$ yields left side that can be $\approx 23,7$. Butter check it, maybe I made some mistake: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimise+9%2B3*%289x%5E2%2B2%2F%283x%5E2%29%29 (I guess star halved the link so copy paste it)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is true and follows from expanding the following expression: 
Consider a vector $x=(x_1,...,x_N)$, and define vectors $X,Y$ as

$X_i:=\frac{2}{N} x_i$ and $Y_i:=-\frac{2}{N^2} \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{x_i-x_j}{\vert x_i- x_j \vert^2}.$

It follows then that

$$ \vert X+Y \vert^2= \frac{4}{N^2} \vert x \vert^2 + \frac{4}{N^4} \sum_{i=1}^N \vert \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{x_i-x_j }{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2} \vert^2+ -\frac{4}{N^3} \sum_{i \neq j } \left( x_i-x_j \right) \frac{\left(x_i-x_j\right)}{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2}$$

Thus, $$ \vert X+Y \vert^2= \frac{4}{N^2} \vert x \vert^2 + \frac{4}{N^4}  \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{1}{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2}  -\frac{4(N-1)}{N^2}.$$

Comment: This calculation is incorrect. I don't see how the second term, the sum of the squared norms of vectors, who are themselves defined as sums, simplifies to the expression in the last row, and the third term would not have $(x_i-x_j)(x_i-x_j)$, but $x_i(x_i-x_j)$, which does not simplify as easily.

Comment: Use that $Y$ is antisymmetric under switching the roles of $x_i$ and $x_j$. Since you sum over all $i$ and $j \neq i$ you can simplify the summand using the antisymmetry to replace $x_i(x_i-x_j) $ by $(x_i-x_j)^2/2$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your argument, what exactly do you mean by $Y$ being antisymmetric? Also, you realize that the $x_i$ are points in the plane, not just real numbers, right?

Comment: OK, I now understand the antisymmetry argument, and it also works for $x_i$ being points in the plane, so I am fine with the third (negative) term in your calculation. I still think the simplification for the middle term is wrong, at least if $x_i$ are vectors. It would still be nice if it works for $x_i$ being real numbers, that would show that there can at least not be a one-dimensional counterexample.

Comment: The calculation doesn't use the fact that the points are in $\mathbb R^2$ - if it was correct, it would also work for points in $\mathbb R^n.$ But if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is an orthonormal basis and we set $x_i=e_i n^{-1/4}$ then $f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=n^{3/2}+\sqrt{2}(n-1)n^{1/2}$ so $n^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_1,...,x_n)$ is $O(n^{5/2}).$ This is a bit simpler than the $\mathbb R^2$ counterexample in Lukas Geyer's answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not true, here is the sketch of a sequence of distributions where your sum asymptotically grows slower than $n^3$. In the following I am using the symbol $\asymp$ for expressions whose ratio is bounded above and below by some positive constants independent of $n$, and similarly $\lesssim$ for inequalities which hold up to a positive constant.

Start with the following construction: Let $R>1$ be an integer, and let $x_{k,l} = (k,l)$ be the points with integer coordinates $k,l \in \{-R,\ldots,R\}$. These are $n=(2R+1)^2 \asymp R^2$ points with 
$$
\sum_{k,l=-R}^R \|x_{k,l}\|^2 = \sum_{k,l=-R}^R (k^2+l^2) \asymp R^4 \asymp n^2.
$$
Furthermore, for any fixed $k_0,l_0 \in \{-R,\ldots,R\}$ we have
$$
\sum_{{k,l=-R}\atop{(k,l) \ne (k_0,l_0)}}^R \frac{1}{\|x_{k,l} - x_{k_0,l_0}\|^2} \le
\sum_{{k,l=-2R}\atop{(k,l) \ne (0,0)}}^{2R} \frac{1}{\|x_{k,l}\|^2} \le
\sum_{m=1}^{2R} \,\, \sum_{\max(|k|,|l|)=m} \frac{1}{\|x_{k,l}\|^2},
$$
which is rearranging the sum into sums over boundaries of concentric squares of radius $m$. The number of integer points on such a boundary (i.e., the number of terms of the inner sum, given the radius $m$) is $\asymp m$, and each term in that sum is $\frac{1}{\| x_{k,l} \|^2} \asymp \frac{1}{m^2}$, so we get that the total sum above is
$$ 
\asymp \sum_{m=1}^{2R} \frac{1}{m} \asymp \ln R \asymp \ln n.
$$
Summing this up over all lattice points $(k_0,l_0)$, we get that
$$
\sum_{{k,l,k_0,l_0=-R}\atop{(k,l) \ne (k_0,l_0)}}^R \frac{1}{\|x_{k,l} - x_{k_0,l_0}\|^2} \lesssim n \ln n.
$$
For your functions $f_i$, where $i$ now runs through all pairs $(k,l)$ as above, we then get
$$
\sum_{k,l=-R}^R f_{k,l}(x_{-R,-R},\ldots,x_{R,R}) \lesssim n^4 + n \ln n,
$$
which obviously is not quite a counterexample yet. However, from the homogeneity of the terms it is immediate that scaling by a factor $\lambda > 0$ leads to
$$
\sum_{k,l=-R}^R f_{k,l}(\lambda x_{-R,-R},\ldots,\lambda x_{R,R}) \lesssim \lambda^2 n^4 + \lambda^{-2} n \ln n.
$$
A choice of $\lambda = n^{-3/4} (\ln n)^{1/4}$ (so that both terms have the same asymptotic behavior) leads to
$$
\sum_{k,l=-R}^R f_{k,l}(\lambda x_{-R,-R},\ldots,\lambda x_{R,R}) \lesssim n^{2.5} \sqrt{\ln n}.
$$
Somehow I suspect that this is actually the lower bound for the asymptotic behavior of your sum for general $(x_i)$, but I don't have a proof of that.